# Passing PIL cropped image as stream in Azure Computer Vision

Tags: python, azure, file, file-upload, python-imaging-library

I need to pass a cropped image to the Computer Vision client in Azure, either as a stream or a url. I'm using PIL to crop the image based on some bounding box values.
img1 stores the cropped image

```
img1 = img.crop((bbox[i][0], bbox[i][1], bbox[i][4], bbox[i][5]))
img1.show()
with open(img1.name, 'rb') as bg_image1:
     colour_analysis = computervision_client.analyze_image_in_stream(bg_image1, remote_image_features)
```

OR

```
img1 = img.crop((bbox[i][0], bbox[i][1], bbox[i][4], bbox[i][5]))
img1.show()
open_image = open(img1.name, "rb")
colour_analysis = computervision_client.analyze_image_in_stream(open_image, remote_image_features)
```

When I run the code above I get the error: raise AttributeError(name) AttributeError: name

Previously, when i uploaded the image from my files, I used this code which worked well:

```
with open('filepath\filename.jpg', 'rb') as bg_image:
    colour_analysis = computervision_client.analyze_image_in_stream(bg_image, remote_image_features)
```

How do I pass the cropped image to the Azure Client?

Comment: Can you please add more details about the remote_image_features that you added.

Comment: That is a simple list that contains the features to be analysed, in my case it's the background colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below github sample to analyze a local image. See the ComputerVisionClient methods, such as AnalyzeImageInStreamAsync.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/blob/master/dotnet/ComputerVision/ImageAnalysisQuickstart.cs#L306